# How to assign a field name to an SQL Count in AWS Athena SQL

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions, presto, amazon-athena

I'm still new to Athena.  I think I got my database defined correctly, as shown in Example 1 below.  However, when I run a count query, I get results unlike what I would expect.

**Example 1: Works Fine except count is called "_col3"**

```
SELECT ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday, count(*) FROM "relatixcurrdayjson"."currday"
where ticker = 'TQQQ'
group by ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday
order by ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday
```

Result:

[image]

**Example 2: syntax error**

```
SELECT ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday, count(*) as 'countperday' FROM "relatixcurrdayjson"."currday"
where ticker = 'TQQQ'
group by ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday
order by ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday
```

This query shows a syntax error when I click "Run Query":
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use single quotes for identifiers. They are meant for literal strings only. If you need to quote an identifier, use double quotes; but here, you don't even need to quote it, since it does not contain special characters.

So:

```
select ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday, count(*) as countperday 
from "relatixcurrdayjson"."currday"
where ticker = 'TQQQ'
group by ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday
order by ticker, timestampmonth, timestampday
```

Redshift folds the identifiers as lower case by default. This means you don't even need to quote the schema and table name in the `from` clause (since they are all lower case).

Comment: Perfect! Quotes are an old habbit from MSSQL.